# Flow type - index signature declaring the expected key / value type is missing in property touches of unknown type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I have problems with event typing. If I do this:

```
function(e: MouseEvent | TouchEvent) {
   const coords = e.touches ? e.touches[0].clientX : e.clientX
}
```

I get this errors

```
 1. Cannot get e.clientX because property clientX is missing in TouchEvent
 2. Cannot get e.touches[0] because an index signature declaring the expected key / value type is
missing in property touches of unknown type
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

In flow the way to check for object type is not to validate if a certain property exists because that's not always sound. Instead you want to make use of `instanceof`.

I changed your function a bit so that it returns but it should be what you're looking for.

```
function getClientX(e: MouseEvent | TouchEvent): number {
  if (e instanceof TouchEvent) {
    return e.touches[0].clientX;
  }
  return e.clientX;
}
```